# Integrate paypal with variable items and record order detail on own server

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

Our website shows a list of items the user can choose. The user can choose several of them and use paypal to checkout. We need to record the order on our own server if the purchase succeed.

I investigated the paypal button solution http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/

However it doesn't seem to satisfy our need. I don't have a chance to record the order and order details(what items are in this order). Also it is highly insecure. So any suggestions on the integration approach.

We are using Spring + jsp as the server if this is relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Several PayPal products you can use:

1. Cart upload. It's part of the website payments standard features. There are ways to make it more secure, but it's still a product meant for entry level merchants.
2. Express checkout. This is a powerful product and does what you want. I'd personally recommend this. Once you get familiar it's very powerful.
3. Other products like those using rest api. I don't like these.

Start with PayPal official developer site: developer.paypal.com and search for these products on it. You'll find what you need.

Comment: -1 "I don't like these" isn't relevant. Why don't you "like" it? Is there a technical issue? There are features (in fact) not _yet_ supported in REST API, that are available in Classic, so just point them out.